# Не срабатывает @media для блока

Tags: css

Привет всем, помогите с вопросом.

```
<div class="week-product__descr--tablet week-product__descr--desk">content</div>
```

у него 2 класса, один для планшетной ширины, второй для десктопной:

.week-product__descr--tablet - селектор для планшета

.week-product__descr--desk - селектор для десктопа

Вопрос в том, что на ширине для десктопа медиа не срабатывает, и применяются стили, которые определенны для планшета.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему и как это можно решить? Для родительского блока и других дочерних все в порядке.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас опечатка, вместо `week-product__descr--desk`, написано `week-product__descr-desk`. Не хватает тире перед `desk`, поэтому применяются стили для планшета.

Answer (score 0):

у вас в медиа запросе прописано min-width без ограничений, добавте например в это же правило max-width и проблема уйдет + селектор для планшета идет ниже в файле css - он будет приоритетнее в стилях